# Get map key based on index

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I want to get a `LinkedHashMap` **key** based on index. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5237147/3913366) and used a `LinkedHashMap` implementation instead of `HashMap` implementation to preserve order of insertion.

I have used below code (from some SO post I can't seem to find) to get Key By Value :

```
private Long getKeyByValue(Map<Long, String> map, String value) {

    for (Map.Entry<Long, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }

    // -1 if key not found
    return (long) -1;
}
```

The problem is, above method is useful only when Map value is not custom or not a collection. In my case, I have a `Map<String, List<Issues>>` where `Issues` is my own defined class and I want to get, say, 2nd key which is `String` based on index which is 2, in this case. Suggestions?

Comment: You need to implement an inner for loop and iterate over the `issues` collection if found Hashmap key can be returned

Answer (score 2):

how about this:

```
static <K> K getKeyByIndex( Map<K,?> sortedMap, int index )
{
    assert index >= 0;
    assert index < sortedMap.size();
    for( K key : sortedMap.keySet() )
    {
        if( index == 0 )
            return key;
        index--;
    }
    assert false; //should never happen.
}
```