# How to get value from a column referenced by a number, from JDBC Response object of Jmeter?

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I know they advice to get a cell value this way:

```
columnValue = vars.getObject("resultObject").get(0).get("Column Name");
```

as stated on [jMeter doc : component reference : JDBC_Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request).

But: How to access the same RS cell value by just a number of the column?

```
RS.get(0).get(4);
```

...instead of giving it a String of column Name/Label.

**edit 1**: Lets use Groovy/Java, instead of BeanShell. Thanks.

**edit 2**: The original motivation was the difference between column Name / Label, as these seem to be not fully guaranteed (? seems to be not clear here, not to me), especially due case-sensitivity ("id"/"ID", "name"/"Name"/"NAME" ..)

Comment: answering your edit 2: definitely use `row.entrySet()` or similar way, as it's the best way to iterate through all entries in map.

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like:

```
String value = (new ArrayList<String>(vars.getObject("resultObject").get(0).values())).get(4)
```

More information: [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter)

---

Be aware that according to [HashMap documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

So the order of columns might be a big question mark.

Answer (score 1):

The row itself is a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), defined in source code as:

```
HashMap<String, Object> row
```

So using BeanShell syntax, you could get it as

```
row = vars.getObject("resultObject").get(0); // returns HashMap
```

In HashMap, you cannot access item (column) by ID. You could, however, apply one of the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237101/is-it-possible-to-get-element-from-hashmap-by-its-position), **but `HashMap` doesn't guarantee order**, so you cannot be sure what "column 4" will contain.

If you want to be able to loop through all columns, it's better to do it in a Map style, not by index. For example using `entrySet()` with BeanShell:

```
for(Map.Entry entry : row.entrySet())
{
    log.info(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
}
```

See various ways to iterate through Map [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-to-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map).