# How shall I iterate in BaseAdapter getView() if I use HashMap

Tags: android

I have an extended from `BaseAdapter` class which used as a custom `Adapter` for my `ListView`. If I use `List<>` as a data set I don't have any troubles in `getView()` method and everything is ok - my list is populated with all data from the `List`. But if I would use  `HashMap` this never works. As far as I understand `getView()` iterates through collection and this works fine with `List` because it is iterable.

```
private class MAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public MAdapter(Context context) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;

            if (v == null) {
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            Task task = taskList.get(position); // works perfect if taskList is List and doesn't work if it is HashMap. What shell I do to use HashMap here?

            if (task != null) {
                TextView tvDescription = (TextView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.task_text_view);
                TextView tvTime = (TextView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.time_text_view);

                if (tvDescription != null) {
                    tvDescription.setText(task.getDescription());
                }

                if (tvTime != null) {
                    tvTime.setText(task.showTime());
                }
            }

            return v;
        }
```

Comment: Try the link it worked best for me


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234576/what-adapter-shall-i-use-to-use-hashmap-in-a-listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter and it's called ListAdapter for a reason. Why do you want to use a HashMap?

**Update:**

Remove from the list.

```
for(int j = list.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--){
  Object o = list.get(j);
  if(o.getId().equals(id)) {
    list.remove(o); // find obj and remove
    break;
  }
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // update ListView
```

or Keep both a list and HashMap. I recommend just using the List.

```
Object o = map.remove(id); // remove object by id
list.remove(o); // remvove object from list
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // update ListView
```

Comment: because I need to remove an object from the collection by its Id and the best way to do it with HashMap not List.

Comment: Just iterate the list and remove it like in my example.