# Creating a custom hashmapadapter

Tags: android

If I have a hashmap containing the following:

```
Hashmap contains (String, String)
```

How can I instantiate a custom adapter? The custom adapter should extend baseadapter. 
I need to combine both key and value so it looks something like "KEY+VALUE", "KEY+VALUE"... and assign this to an array VALUES. The array VALUES is used later on when I insantiate my custom adpter.

Instantiation should look something like this:

```
MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, VALUES);   
setListAdapter(adapter)
```

I am lost here so code would be a big help.

THANKS
graham

The following list is using as its datasource a string array called items.

```
public ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items));
```

however items is a string array which I would like to stop using and instead start using concatenated key+value pairs from my hashmap

so instead of the user being presented a list of items he will be presented a list of key+value pairs taken from the hashmap hm

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do... If you want to show to the user a list of key+value pairs you have just to use the code in my answer. Try to see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234576/what-adapter-shall-i-use-to-use-hashmap-in-a-listview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use a custom adapter. Your layout is quite simple, you need only a textView, so you can use ArrayAdapter.
For you example you can do:

```
HashMap<Integer,String>hm=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
Vector<String>elements=new Vector<String>();
```

> ```
>  for(int i=0; i<=10;i){      
>       hm.put(i,("num"+i));
>     }
>     for (Entry<Integer, String> e : hm.entrySet()) {
>         String newString=e.toString();
>         elements.add(newString);
>     }
>     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, elements);
>     list.setAdapter(adapter);
> ```

Comment: Hi, It looks better now but in my list I get 0=num1.... I want populate it with the values for the following hashmap hm.put ("one", "Apple"); hm.put("two", "Mango"); hm.put("three", "Grape"); the values and keys should be concented in elements                           thanks

Comment: FIGURED IT OUT for(int i=0; i<=10;i++) { hm.put(1, "Apple"); hm.put(2, "Mango"); hm.put(3, "Grape"); hm.put(4, "Orange"); hm.put(5, "Peach"); } for (Entry<Integer, String> e : hm.entrySet()) { String newString=e.toString(); elements.add(newString); }

Comment: How do you want them to appear on the list? Only Apple, Mango and Grape? To do that you have only to change the `e.toString()` with `e.getValue().toString()`.

Comment: Hi, I see one more problem i have declared public ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items));    and items is a string array. How can I update this to incluce hm.put(1, "Apple");    
  hm.put(2, "Mango");     
  hm.put(3, "Grape");    
  hm.put(4, "Orange");     
  hm.put(5, "Peach");

Comment: What is `myList` and what `items` contain? Could you please edit your first question with your code, otherwise I can't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: updated the list, I want to stop using a String of items and instead use key+value pairs

Comment: Edit your question with your code, so I can better understand what's your problem

Comment: The following list is using as its datasource a string array called items. 

public ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items));  however items is a string array which I would like to stop using and instead start using concatenated key+value pairs from my hashmap

so instead of the user being presented a list of items he will be presented a list of key+value pairs taken from the hashmap hm