# ArrayList data to ListView

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have collection of `HashMap<String,Object>` data as `ArrayList`.

I used following method to add `HashMap` data to `ArrayList`.

```
mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
for (Data dt : data) {

    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();                
    map.put("id", dt.getWeekNo());
    map.put("description", dt.getDesc());
    map.put("Amount", dt.getAmount());
    mylist.add(map);
}
```

`Data` is a separate class which is used to `Getters` and `Setters` purpose only.

Now my output is like:

```
3 | Income  | 1000
5 | Income  | 1500
3 | Expense |  250
5 | Expense |  500
```

I want it as the following to my listview.

```
3 | Income : 1000 | Expense : 250
5 | Income : 1500 | Expense : 500
```

Any idea to achieve this. I dont know how to achieve and I dont know any idea too so I dont know where to start.

Updates :
This is the way I am adapt my list to listview with `getview()` method

```
ListAdapter adapter
    = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.txnlist,
                        new String[] {"id", "description", "Amount" },
                        new int[] { R.id.txntext1, R.id.txntext2, R.id.txntext3 }) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.txnlist, null);
        }
        Collection<Object> str = mylist.get(position).values();
        ArrayList<Object> al1 = new ArrayList<Object>(str);
        TextView amnt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txntext3);
        if (al1.get(2).toString().equals("Income")) 
            amnt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        if (al1.get(2).toString().equals("Expense"))
            amnt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        return super.getView(position, v, parent);
    }
};
ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.repListView);
```

Help me friends.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create custom adpter and override getView()

Comment: where is your code, in which you are adding data to listView. add that here too

Comment: @NiravRanpara I have overrided. I dont know how to bring `Income` and `Expense` of a week together.

Comment: you can check `id` value in your HashMap data list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234576/what-adapter-shall-i-use-to-use-hashmap-in-a-listview

Comment: Are you talking about the listview layout you want to get or the data in itself? Where did you get the output? The question is not very clear.

Comment: Just redesign your class `Data`. Put two different member variables for `Income` and `Expense` field instead of one description Its same applicable for `Amount` also. The main problem of your design Data class is You have different objects with same `id`.

Comment: Share your getView() codes here

Comment: @PankajKumar,@Nirav Ranpara. See updates.

Comment: @YoannHercouet I will get the output in `ListView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wow, I haven't got the slightest clue why you would do the variables to hold the data like that, but in any case, based on what I understood, you want something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<(myList.getCount()/2); i++){
    Log.v("Line " + i, myList.getItem(i).getWeekNo() + "|" + 
        myList.getItem(i).getDesc() + ":" + myList.getItem(i).getAmount() + "|" + 
        myList.getItem(mylist.getCount()/2 + i).getDesc() + ":" + 
            mylist.getItem(myList.getCount()/2 + i).getAmount();
}
```

Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an Adapter and override the method "getView(...)". Inside of getView you have to inflate your layout for each item of the listview and you have to assign your values.

Here an example http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429