# In Android adding column name to ListView columns

Tags: android

I am using ListView and have successfully populated it with the data of a database table using SimpleCursorAdapter .My question is how to add Column names of the database table, to the columns generated in the ListView.

Comment: Check this out mate, I had a similar problem at hand some days earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532850/treemap-to-listview-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include your `ListView` row layout at the top of your `ListView` Element in Xml.

```
<include layout="@layout/report_row"/>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/YourList"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    >
    </ListView>
```

or you can add a `HeaderView` to your list which contains a ViewGroup of your List columns

```
YourList.addHeaderView(View, null, false);
```

Comment: Very IMPORTANT!: adding header view shifts your list items by 1, meaning that list[0] is now the header view, even though it is sticky.

you can have a view separate from your list, and maintain it standalone